# Radio Button in cakephp in Same line

Tags: css, cakephp

[image]

what is problem in this radio Button are not dispaly in same line

i change the Css file  like my code is here

```
.css
{ 
  display:inline-box;
 }
```

my Html like this

```
<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('subscription_id',array('label'=>' package_name','type'=>'radio','options'=>$view,'id'=>'packagename'));?></td>
```

Comment: Could you post your entire code in jsfiddle and give us the link, it would simplify things for us

Comment: did you mean "inline-block"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `display: inline`

```
.css
{ 
  display:inline;
 }
```

Comment: not working ... this are done by me  till not working this code any another

Comment: please post the html/css that you currently have or try putting it on jsfiddle so we could properly help you with this. :)